# Why did I get error when using lag function in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    [Return],
    lag([Return]) over (order by [Date]) as [Yesterday Price] 
from t3
```

For the above code, I got error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
>   'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Anyone knows the reason?

My table structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0J1W.png)

Comment: which version SQLare you using

Comment: Wjhat's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? You most likely have the **2014** Management Studio, but you're working against an older **database engine version** which just doesn't support `LAG` yet (that was a new feature in SQL Server **2012**)

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
ALTER DATABASE yourDBName
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Comment: I think COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL provides only partial backward compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server. So `LAG` will still work